# How do I create a Staging environment using Wordpress, MyPHPadmin and Bitbucket?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp, bitbucket, staging

I need to create a local copy of a website in order to start testing and learning without updating the main website. I have installed wordpress locally and imported the SQL database into myphpadmin (Using XAMPP) I was also given a wordpress core codebase from Bitbucket. I am having difficulties understanding how to go about it from here. How do I create the website copy with these files and are there plugins in wp I have to use? I'm sorry if that's a little obvious, I am very new to this.

I installed Wordpress, imported the SQL database into myPhpadmin, created a repo in Bitbucket and I have a working default wordpress website.

Comment: Have you tried copying the full WP folder and full DB to your local?